# Im having this error module not found due to my node version in the tutorial its showing use require but im using import and facing issue importing

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, module, routes

app.js

Importing from auth.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import router from './router/auth';

app.use(router);
```

while using app.use its giving an error module not found which is router module

Here is the problem (Showing Module not found) `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module`

Exporting from auth.js

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World from server auth.js');
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `.js` after auth?

```
import router from './router/auth.js';
```

Comment: Wow man thanks brother solved my issue but can you explain it why it was like that caz in react we dont have to put an extension like .js but how come now in normal project